# how to change the src of element with jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, src

I have a video player and i want above it some anchors when clicking on them, the src of the video is changed. How can i do that? By preference without page refresh

So it should look like this:

```
<a href="#">Video 1</a> <!-- load video1.mp4 -->
<a href="#">Video 2</a> <!-- load video2.mp4 -->
<a href="#">Video 3</a> <!-- load video3.mp4 -->

<video class="myVideo" controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350" >
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> <!--this src should be changed by onclick-->
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `data()` to store data (video source) on your `<a>`.

can update the source of video by using `attr()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default behaviour of <a>
    var scr = $(this).data("src"); //Get the data-src attribute of <a>
    $(".myVideo source").attr("src", scr); //Assign the value on the video

    var video = $(".myVideo source");
    video.get().load(); //Load the video
    video.get().play(); //Play the video
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-src="video1.mp4">Video 1</a>
<!-- load video1.mp4 -->
<a href="#" data-src="video2.mp4">Video 2</a>
<!-- load video2.mp4 -->
<a href="#" data-src="video3.mp4">Video 3</a>
<!-- load video3.mp4 -->

<video class="myVideo" controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350">
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> <!--this src should be changed by onclick-->
</video>
```

**Docs:**

Data: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Attr: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: i can see the src changes in the source when click on anchor but the video keeps playing video1.mp4

Answer (score 1):

- You can add `data-attribute` to your links with the proper video url.
- Bind an event to your links.
- When a link is clicked, prevent the default behavior.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var source = $(this).data('source');
  console.log('Chaning to "' + source + '"');
  $('.myVideo source').attr('src', source);  
  $('.myVideo').load();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-source='video1.mp4' href="#">Video 1</a>
<!-- load video1.mp4 -->
<a data-source='video2.mp4' href="#">Video 2</a>
<!-- load video2.mp4 -->
<a data-source='video3.mp4' href="#">Video 3</a>
<!-- load video3.mp4 -->

<video class="myVideo" controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350">
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> <!--this src should be changed by onclick-->
</video>
```

## Resource

- [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: i can see the src changes in the source when click on anchor but the video keeps playing video1.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Have a data attribute to your a tag and video. Then you'd able to do

```
<a class="videoLink" href="#" data-url="video1.mp4" >Video 1</a> <!-- load video1.mp4 -->
```

Then with script

```
$(".videoLink").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myVideo source').attr('src', $(this).attr("data-url"));
})
```

**Note :**

Some browsers may not change the video after changing the `src`. In such cases you need to call the load function on them.

```
$('#myVideo').load();
```

Comment: Use `data` function to get the information rather than `attr` function.

Comment: You don't really need to in this case.

Comment: Your approach works perfectly, however, it's fancier and cleaner to use the function `data`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default behaviour of <a>
    var scr = $(this).data("src"); //Get the data-src attribute of <a>
    $(".myVideo source").attr("src", scr); //Assign the value on the video
    $(".myVideo")[0].load();
      $(".myVideo")[0].play()
   
  });
});
    </script>
```

```html
<a href="#" data-src="vds/intro_1.mp4" >Video 1</a>
<!-- load video1.mp4 -->
<a href="#" data-src="vds/intro_2.mp4" >Video 2</a>
<!-- load video2.mp4 -->
<a href="#" data-src="vds/intro_3.mp4" >Video 3</a>
<!-- load video3.mp4 -->

<video class="myVideo" autoplay controls preload="auto" width="600" height="350">
  <source src="vds/intro_1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> <!--this src should be changed by onclick-->
</video>
```

Comment: This will load the Video on click and Play